# Karate UI: Get current browser's URL

Tags: ui-automation, karate

Is there a way to get the current URL in the browser's address bar?
Is there any replacement for the following code which does not work, perhaps as mentioned [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/595):

```
  And def url =  function() {return window.location.href}
  Then print url()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `driver.url` is what you are looking for: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driverurl

```
 * match driver.url == 'https://some/url'
```

Note that to avoid flaky tests, this may be better:

```
 * waitForUrl('https://some/url')
```

Comment: Actually, I had tried driver.url before but it did not work as I was missing waitForURL. Thanks for making me avoid "flaky tests".

Comment: @UIC great, I'll make it more clear in the docs. something that may be useful to know is that `waitForUrl()` uses a string "contains" match so a part of the expected URL is enough, e.g. `/some/path` and does not need to start with `http`